# sfdx unexpected token error

Tags: salesforcedx

I had sfdx working like 10 minutes before.  However, now it is crapping out:

```
$ sfdx force
module.js:96
    throw e;
    ^

SyntaxError: Error parsing C:\Users\wlee0264\AppData\Local\sfdx\plugins\node_modules\salesforcedx\package.json: Unexpected token � in JSON at position 1
    at Object.parse (native)
    at readPackage (module.js:92:52)
    at tryPackage (module.js:102:13)
    at Function.Module._findPath (module.js:186:20)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:467:25)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\wlee0264\AppData\Local\sfdx\tmp\heroku-script-658969795:10:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
```

The only thing I remember doing was messing with ssh keys when pushing to github.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like my AppData\Local cache was corrupted.  All I did was delete the entire folder \AppData\Local\sfdx and had to re-download the plugins.  Everything started working after that.